# Careers: Relocation icon looks disabled

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The relocation icon/badge looks like it is disabled. In the example below, it looks like the company offers visa sponsorship, but does not offer relocation. But as far as I can tell this icon is only ever displayed on jobs that do offer relocation.

[image: relocation icon]

Can the icon be changed to have a more obvious colour e.g. green? If there is such a thing as "relocation not offered", then a more obvious icon would also be great.

Comment: The relocation could be green or blue.

Comment: I'd vote for blue. Green almost looks like a success message or something about money (even if relocation is a monetary bonus). Not to mention blue would be less of an intense contrast with the orange, I'd think.

Comment: I'd vote for the colors of the flag matching the country the user chose while selecting the *Will you relocate* option (*If so, where?* option).

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula what about multi color flags..? we generate a gradient..? :s

Comment: @TJ we could have up to two colors: one for *offers* and one for *relocation*. But you do know I'm joking, right? :)

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula After seeing all the stuff people post here for long lime, I've almost lost the ability to figure out who's joking ._.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Fix incoming.

Comment: Just as a side note: Having red and green next to each other is a very bad design, due to the fact that a big amount of male users are red-green colour blind. Therefore, they will see two times the same colour instead of two different ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix will be live in the next prod build. We chose blue-gray because true blue is already used for links and buttons, while green is for compensation data.

[image: relocation data styling fix]